# Bootstrap glyphicon error: square instead of icon

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Im trying to build responsive website. To do that, Im using Bootstrap 3. I have downloaded Bootstrap 3 and imported to my website root directory:

[image: folder]

I don't know why, but on small screen it doesn't show my icon:

[image: icon]

My code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="lt">

<head>

    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../bootstrap-3.2.0-dist/css/bootstrap-theme.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../bootstrap-3.2.0-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/reset.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/styles.css">

    <script src="../js/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
    <script src="../bootstrap-3.2.0-dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/script.js"></script>

    <title>
        title
    </title>

</head>

<body>

    <header class="top" role="header">
        <div class="container">
            <a href="../aplikacija/app.html" class="navbar-brand pull-left">
                Application
            </a>
            <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="glyphicon-align-justify"></span>
            </button>
            <nav class="navbar-collapse collapse" role="navigation">
                <ul class="navbar-nav nav">
                    <li><a href="../aplikacija/app.html">APP</a></li>
                    <li><a href="../ux/ux.html">UX</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </header>

    <div id="app" class="content">

    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: hm, when you use an css reset this should be first loaded css file. Bootstrap has his own "reset" normalize.css

Comment: Does it work if you link css directly from bootstrap CDN: <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

Comment: I moved reset.css to the top of css declaration. But this doesn't solve my problem...

Comment: I have tried bootstrap CDN. Still doesn't work.

Comment: take a look at the network tab in devtools, if all files are loaded  proper

Comment: Thanks for indirectly reminding me to [implement a check for this](https://github.com/twbs/bootlint/pull/118).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your glyphicon span should have the following class: `glyphicon glyphicon-align-justify` as opposed to just `glyphicon-align-justify`

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest not using align justify in the span as a class - just display the glyphicon and then justify it in an outside div.

```
<div class="text-justify">
     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-align-justify"></span> 
</div>
```

here is some more info - http://getbootstrap.com/components/#glyphicons-how-to-use

Comment: Just realised that you were trying to use the icon align justify and not justify the glyicon :P So as James king said - you just made an error in the class of the span.

Comment: Yes, but it is only matter of design. Lets say I just have to make layout symbol. It should be possible to use it, right?